# joining multiple common table expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have two Query, Query1:

```
with cte as (
select
        dbo.Cable.*,
        row_number() over(partition by dbo.Cable.TagNo order by dbo.Cable.CableRevision desc) as rn
    from dbo.Cable 
    where (dbo.Cable.CableRevision = @CoreRevision )  
    )
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

and also  Query2

```
with cte as (
select
        dbo.Cable.TagNo,dbo.Core.*,
        row_number() over(partition by dbo.Core.CoreNo order by dbo.Core.CoreRevision desc) as rn
    from dbo.Core INNER JOIN 
     dbo.Cable ON dbo.Cable.Id = dbo.Core.CableId
    where  (dbo.Core.CoreRevision <= @CoreRevision  )
    )
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

these two query are related by `Query1.TagNo` and `Query2.TagNo` 
how can i use join these two querys, is it possible to do that with `With` Command?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using `SQL Server 2008` ?

Comment: You can have multiple CTEs in a query, so just add them together. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134320/combining-multiple-cte-in-tsql

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this query, perhaps this is what you are looking for.

```
;WITH cte AS
 (SELECT dbo.Cable.*, 
         row_number() over(partition by dbo.Cable.TagNo order by dbo.Cable.CableRevision desc) as rn
  FROM dbo.Cable 
  WHERE dbo.Cable.CableRevision = @CoreRevision
  ), cte2 AS
 (SELECT dbo.Cable.TagNo, dbo.Core.*, 
         row_number() over(partition by dbo.Core.CoreNo order by dbo.Core.CoreRevision desc) as rn
  FROM dbo.Core INNER JOIN dbo.Cable ON dbo.Cable.Id = dbo.Core.CableId
  WHERE dbo.Core.CoreRevision <= @CoreRevision
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte c FULL JOIN cte2 c2 ON c.TagNo = c2.TagNo
  WHERE c.rn = 1 OR c2.rn = 1
```

Comment: it brings back just a part of result

Comment: Try to use the FULL JOIN instead of INNER JOIN in the last SELECT statement

Answer (score 7):

```
with cte as 
(
    select
        dbo.Cable.*,
        row_number() over(partition by dbo.Cable.TagNo order by dbo.Cable.CableRevision desc) as rn
    from dbo.Cable 
    where (dbo.Cable.CableRevision = @CoreRevision )  
), 
cte2 as (
    select
        dbo.Cable.TagNo,dbo.Core.*,
        row_number() over(partition by dbo.Core.CoreNo order by dbo.Core.CoreRevision desc) as rn
    from dbo.Core INNER JOIN 
     dbo.Cable ON dbo.Cable.Id = dbo.Core.CableId
    where  (dbo.Core.CoreRevision <= @CoreRevision  )
    )
select *
from cte
  join cte2 on cte1.TagNo = cte2.TagNo
where cte.rn = 1 and cte2.rn = 1;
```

I don't know if the condition `cte.rn = 1 and cte2.rn = 1` is what you want. Maybe you just want it on one of the CTEs, maybe on both, maybe you actually want an outer join with `cte2.rn = 1` in the join condition...