# Combining multiple cte

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to combine a result of two cte to another cte.  I wrote a query combining two cte.  The result gave a three column data in which I want to group the third column and averaging the second column.  The second column resulted from a case sum statement.

Comment: Post the query you tried already.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941275/joining-multiple-common-table-expressions

I hope that helps. Is that what you are looking to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking whether you can re-use CTEs after they have been used in a query, the answer is no.  You can't do this:

```
 with A
 as (
    -- query
 )
 select A.*
 from   A;

 -- this is a separate query
 select id
    ,   count(*)
 from   A
 group by 
        id
```

You can, however, combine CTEs in all kinds of ways, as long as you do it in a single statement.  You can do this, which uses the hypothetical CTE `A` in two CTEs and the final query:

```
 with A
 as  (
    -- some query
 )
 ,   ACustomers
 as  (
     select *
     from   Customers
         join A
             on ....
 )
 ,   AVendors
 as  (
     select *
     from   Vendors
         join A
              on ....
 )
 select  A.StateId
    ,    ACount = COUNT(*)
    ,    CustomerCount = (select count(*) from ACustomers ac where ac.StateId = A.StateId )
    ,    VendorCount = (select count(*) from AVendors av where av.StateId = A.StateId )
 from    A
 group by 
        A.StateId
```

Comment: @Arvin  I don't know, but I've done at least 8 on occasion.  I looked and couldn't find a limit stated anywhere.